# Why does my C# method (algorithm) not always return a value and sometimes loops forever instead?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-theory

Let's say there is a 2D room with a shape of a circle. There are connectors of various types on its boundary and we are to decide, whether we can pair the connectors with cables so that no two cables cross.

I have a string array of connectors (names), that represent the order of connectors around the room from a certain point. I made an algorithm, that takes the first connector as a reference. Since every connector has to be paired with another connector of the same type, the first one must as well. I loop over the remaining connectors and use recursion to find out, whether it is or isn't possible to pair the rest with no cables crossing. So for example, if I have 10 connectors on the boundary of the room and the connector at index 7 is the first one of the same type as the one at index 0, then I check (using recursion), if I can pair connectors within the range of indexes 1-6 (I couldn't connect 6 and 8 for example, since it would cross the cable connecting 1 and 7) and also if I can pair connectors at indexes 8 and 9.

Example where connection is possible

[image]

Here is my code. The while loop is guaranteed to accept only lists, that have even number of values inside. But still, my code loops sometimes. Can anyone explain why?

```
static bool IsPossible(List<string> connectors)              
{
    int index = 1;
    string firstConnector = connectors[0];
    bool possible = false;

    if (connectors.Count % 2 == 1)       // making sure there is even number, so we can pair
    {
        return false;
    }

    while ((!possible) && (index <= connectors.Count - 1))
    {
        if (connectors[index] == firstConnector)
        {
            if ((index == 1) && (index == connectors.Count - 1))   // this connector is just next to the first one and it is the last one at the same time 
            {
                possible = true;
            }
            else if ((index == 1) && (index != connectors.Count - 1))      // this connector is just next to the first one and it is not the last one
            {
                possible = IsPossible(connectors.GetRange(2, connectors.Count - 2));
            }
            else if (index != connectors.Count - 1)      // this connector is neither next to the first one nor the last one
            {
                List<string> leftSublist = connectors.GetRange(1, index - 1);
                List<string> rightSublist = connectors.GetRange(index + 1, connectors.Count - index - 1);

                possible = IsPossible(leftSublist) && IsPossible(rightSublist);
            }
            else if (index == connectors.Count - 1)        // this connector is the last one and it isn't next to the first one
            {
                possible = IsPossible(connectors.GetRange(1, index - 1));
            }
        }
                
        index += 2;   // we jump by two, so that we can always pair in our sublists
    }

    return possible;
}
```

Please don't judge my code, I did it just for fun and I'm not a programmer :) Thank you for any help or advice.

I expected the function to always end (just out of logic - the index gets bigger and the while loop should therefore end at some time). However, it looks like as if an infinite list appeared somewhere, because for this input

```
List<string> example = new List<string> { "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B", "SATA", "USB - B" }
```

it doesn't return any value and continues looping.

Answer (score 0):

```
- WHILE unconnected connectors remain
   - SET click = false
   - LOOP C over connectors
       - IF connector of same type as C adjacent to C ( ignoring connected )
           - Link connector pair
           - REMOVE connector pair
           - SET click = true
           - BREAK out of LOOP C
   - END LOOP C
   - IF click == false
      - REPORT failure
      - STOP
- END WHILE
- REPORT SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typical *stack* problem. Note, that you can safely connect neighbors only (and remove them from the problem):

```
 ... A B B C A B ...
       | |
     we can connect and remove them and have a shorter problem
 
     A C A B
```

**Code:**

```
private static bool CanConnect(IEnumerable<string> sockets) {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(sockets);
      
    Stack<string> agenda = new();
        
    foreach (string socket in sockets) 
        if (agenda.TryPeek(out var last) && last == socket)
            agenda.Pop(); // Neighbors can be connected and removed
        else
            agenda.Push(socket);
          
    return agenda.Count == 0; // No unconnected sockets 
}
```

**Demo:**

```
var test = new List<string>() {
  "usb", "sata", "usb", "usb", "sata", "usb"
};

bool result = CanConnect(test);

Console.Write(result);
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n45r26)

Comment: @Terezie Kladivová: You are welcome! Hope, you have solved your algorithmic problem.